# servlet response.sendredirect not working in domain name

Tags: servlets, response.redirect

I have a servlet that use sendredirect to jsp after processing request from the client. It not working if the client send request to the server using web's dns (https://domainName.com/webApp/Order)

Our network admin already map the dns (https://domainName.com/webApp) inside reserve proxy to point the "http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/webApp/" in loadbalacing.

What it the problem and how to solve it? it is the dns problem or the servlet problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the response.sendRedirect, i need to put the full url (https://domainName.com/webApp/sucesss.jsp)
if there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you use web's dns (http://domainName.com/webApp/Order) the default port 80 is used (HTTP) . And when you use `http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/webApp/Order` you specify the the port number for your tomcat server (here it is  8080).

Try using this and it should work easily with the dns also.

```
http://domainName.com:8080/webApp/Order
```

See the port number (8080 or any port number on which your tomcat is running) I have added after the dns name